# jQuery Slide up and down from botton element

Tags: jquery

When I add a second link to open another element using jQuery, the up and down slider doesn't work. I don't know how to add another element to the jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function( $ ){

        // Get a reference to the container.
        var container = $( "#container" );


        // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
        $( "a" ).click(
        function( event ){
            // Prevent the default event.
            event.preventDefault();

            // Toggle the slide based on its current
            // visibility.
            if (container.is( ":visible" )){

                // Hide - slide up.
                container.slideUp( 1000 );

            } else {

                // Show - slide down.
                container.slideDown( 1000 );

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The page is http://tinyurl.com/pksro4z

Comment: I have checked this link and script is working. Can you please elaborate your query or can show something in jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry but I'm new, with both links you will see the same element from botton, I don't know how link another statement to another elementto come from botton, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you learn [jquery selector-w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) or [jquery selector link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), which is used to find the proper object like find object by id or css or tag.

You get above issue because the reason is you given anchor tag click. So it will apply to all anchor.

```
$( "a" ).click(...
```

You need to give id to all anchor

```
<a id="ashowWithSlidown" href="#">Show Div With SlideDown()</a>
<a id="ashow" href="#">Show Div</a>
```

Now apply click to each with Id  like

```
$( "#ashowWithSlidown" ).click(function( event ){ alert('this is "ashowWithSlidown"') ;});

and 

$( "#ashow" ).click(function( event ){ alert('this is "ashow"') 
; });
```

Also change class for height like

```
#container {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 151px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You are written the same code in both anchor, what do you want? you have to change code for various object as you ask.